# Kettle error to connect to mysql Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed

Tags: pentaho, kettle

```
2023/09/13 12:03:46 - Kitchen - Logging is at level : Basic
2023/09/13 12:03:46 - Kitchen - Start of run.
2023/09/13 12:03:46 - RepositoriesMeta - Reading repositories XML file: /home/batch/.kettle/repositories.xml
2023/09/13 12:03:48 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Start of job execution
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : A serious error occurred during job execution:
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Communications link failure
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Communications link failure
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:497)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:389)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:360)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:350)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.beginProcessing(Job.java:987)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:477)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:389)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Communications link failure
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:605)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:481)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  ... 6 more
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:589)
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  ... 7 more
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2023/09/13 12:05:59 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
```

i get this error when the script try to connect to mysql

How to fix this error. port is allowed. tried to change the driver.

Comment: Yes, this looks like a driver issue. Please confirm if you are using the right version of MYSQL driver. Pentaho 9.2 supports version 5 and 8. [Check here for the supported drivers](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.2/Setup/JDBC_drivers_reference#r_pentaho_my_sql_jdbc_drivers_reference). Also it would be best to test the database connectivity before executing the PDI job.